# How to change data on a Moodle Form when non-submit button pressed

Tags: moodle, moodle-api

I have a Moodle form which contains a button which has been registered as a no submit button:

```
$mform->registerNoSubmitButton('preloadtest');
$mform->addElement('submit', 'preloadtest', 'Generate Test Data');
```

When this is pressed I can detect this:

```
if ($mform->no_submit_button_pressed()) {
    $data = $mform->get_submitted_data();

    if ($data->preloadtest) {
        //TODO change some form value here before redisplaying form
    }

    $mform->set_data($data);
    echo $OUTPUT->header();
    $mform->display();
}
```

But I have not been able to find a way of changing the value of form elements (like a text box, autocomplete or select) in my code.

I have tried changing the values in `$data` and looked for methods in `$mform` to change values, but only seem to be able to change default values which get overriden by the submitted values.

Comment: Have you tried adding a definition_after_data() function to your form, and adding/removing elements in that? Alternatively, you can override the set_data() function to transform the data, before it is applied to your form?

Comment: Thanks @davosmith, I will experiment with those and report back.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up solving this (may or may not be the right way) by using the Moodle form's setConstants method to overwrite any submitted values that I want to change.

In my form I added a function to access the private _form property and setConstants method:

```
public function setConstants($data)
{
    $this->_form->setConstants($data);
}
```

Then in my form processing, I detect no submit button pressed and update any values I need to change based on the submitted values:

```
if ($mform->no_submit_button_pressed()) {
    $data = $mform->get_submitted_data();

    $constants = [];

    if ($data->button1) {
        $constants['field1'] = 'newvalueforbutton1';
    } elseif ($data->button2) {
        $constants['field1'] = 'newvalueforbutton2';
    }

    $mform->setConstants($constants);
}
```